# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in Production

Tags: reactjs, heroku

We have a Node back-end en react front-end application hosted on Heroku.

On the Heroku Server we get some pages with the error message. React works fine on the localhost.

We tried a different "react scripts": "3.1.2" and "react scripts": "3.2.0." we were on version 3.0.1.

The error=

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtcWc.jpg)

Our react package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.1",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.30.16",
"@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
"ajv": "6.9.1",
"animate.css": "3.7.0",
"axios": "^0.18.1",
"classnames": "2.2.6",
"history": "4.7.2",
"http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.0",
"moment": "2.24.0",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"nouislider": "13.1.0",
"prop-types": "15.7.1",
"react": "16.8.1",
"react-animate-on-scroll": "2.1.5",
"react-datetime": "2.16.3",
"react-dom": "16.8.1",
"react-ga": "^2.5.7",
"react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
"react-image-gallery": "0.8.12",
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "3.1.2",
"react-slick": "0.23.2",
"react-swipeable-views": "0.13.1",
"react-table": "^6.9.2",
"react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-form": "^8.1.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Error solved. The problem was with the "react-table": "^6.9.2", see:

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1686